# return the value in a struct from method of a class

Tags: c++, methods, struct

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct AccountInfo
{
    int Acnumber;
    char ID;
};

class Account
{
    public:
        AccountInfo Operation(void)
        {
            AccountInfo s;
            s.ID = 'M';
            return s;

        }
};

int main()
{
    Account a;
    AccountInfo s = a.Operation();
    cout << s.ID << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to return the values given to a structure inside the method of a class. The code compiles with errors. I tried using an object, it compiles successfully, but doesn't output anything.

What is the problem with my code?

Comment: What do you mean you "tried using an object"?

Comment: instead of struct, I defined a class and created an object of that class inside Account class.

Comment: Can you show that code please.

Comment: #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class AccountInfo
{
   public:
    int Acnumber;
    char ID;
};

class Account
{
    public:
        AccountInfo Operation(void)
        {
            AccountInfo s;
            s.ID = 'M';
            return s;

        }
};

int main()
{
    Account a;
    AccountInfo s = a.Operation();
    cout << s.ID << endl;

    return 0;
}

Can I return the data given inside the method?

Comment: When I run your code the compiler tells me that you're missing a semicolon after the class definition and that the data members you're trying to access from the `AccountInfo` object are private. To fix this, add a semicolon `;` at the ending brace of the `Account` class and add `public:` over the data members of `AccountInfo`. Either that or make `AccountInfo` a `struct` instead of a `class` thereby making its members publicly-accessible by default.

Comment: Do I put a public inside struct?

Comment: Nope. Not in this case you don't.

Comment: Are you experiencing any more problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct Operation(void)
```

What type does this function return? It can't be `struct` because that's not a type, it's a keyword denoting a structure definition. Judging from the return value and how you are using it, I'm assuming you're trying to return an `AccountInfo` object:

```
AccountInfo Operation()
{
    AccountInfo s;
    s.ID = 'M';
    return s;
}
```

The `void` is also not needed for empty parameters. Moreover, you need to make the type of `s` in `main()` `AccountInfo` as well:

```
int main()
{
    Account a;
    AccountInfo s = a.Operation();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that's right. It's a typo. I have to substitute AccountInfo in place of struct.

I just wanted to get M in my output. Is that possible?

Comment: @Pgram Of course it's possible. If you fully implement the suggestions I've given you, you'll get the correct output. [Here is a working example.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96572c26163c5c0e)

Comment: Awesome, thanks Mr.0x499602D2.

I've another quick question. Is it possible to get output without initializing s i.e. 

AccountInfo s = a.Operation();

Is there something like (a.Operation()).ID ?

Comment: I changed the code by replacing struct with a method and the code is identical, it doesn't return the object. Is there an issue here?

Comment: @Pgram Well I need the code to determine the problem. Can you please supply it by using [this website](http://stacked-crooked.com), pasting in your code, clicking "Share" and copying the link from the address bar and pasting it as a comment? That way we won't clutter the comments section with code. :)

Comment: @Pgram The error is simple: "`cout` was not declared in this scope". You forgot to do `#include <iostream>`. When I add that in the code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Change `struct` to `AccountInfo` everywhere except for the initial declaration.